# Android app crashes change the status bar background to white - how can I fix this?

Tags: android, darkmode

I have a problem with Android's status bar.
when the app runs normally the status bar is still visible to the user but when the app crashes the app will be restarts and the status bar color has changed to white.
any idea for this issue? Thank

note: the issue occurs only Android >= 10

| normal | after crash |
| --- | --- |
| [in case normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uASJ.png) | [after crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF0yL.png) |

StatusBar color not changed

Comment: you should include the code you're using to change the status bar.

Comment: Please include the code or crash stack traces so that we can see what's the reason behind the crash.

Comment: @Collins Im using window.statusBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.background_light) in onCreate Activity for change status bar.
after app crash, activity has restart and status bar color changed to white

Comment: @Dev4Life I not find reason lead to crash, Im fixing error status is white after app has been crash. do you have any idea for me

Comment: @NguyễnHữuThuận I can't provide a solution blindly. Just find when the app crashes. Because in most of cases, when the app crashes, it changes some configs like status bar color and so to match the default system color. That's why it's happening. So If you find out what is causing the crash, then you'll be able to solve it easily.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dev4Life & Collins
Thank you for your support
I fixed this problem by adding
window.decorView.windowInsetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(
                  APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS,
                  APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS
)
to onResume function, when the app is restarted the status bar is also reset to APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS

Comment: @NguyễnHữuThuận Great you found the problem. Have fun!